# Ubuntu hangs at "Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen"

Tags: boot, hardware, plymouth

I was running my xubuntu-machine during the night. In the morning I wanted to check something out and I noted that the computer does not respond anymore. It didn't even send a signal to my monitor. Anyway, I shut the machine down and restarted it. Afterwards, I restarted it, passed the boot menu and got stuck at "Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen".

My observations so far:

Generally, my computer seems to work be pretty slowly. When I enter the grub menu everything takes ages. That's why I tried MemCheck, in order to check whether the RAM is ok! => Seems to be ok ( I just run it an 3 hours, It passed to passes, and eventually got stuck again:) ). 
Another weird issue is that I cannot load a live-system or anything. I prepared a bootable USB to install a new ubuntu system but I end up with a black screen with only a cursor at the top left.

It seems to my that it is a HW issue.

I would like to check the CPU, but do not know which onboard-applications I can use (As everything takes ages I cannot really install anything, or update anything).

Partially, I can make to a TTY session but mostly I do not reach it. In the recovery (grub) mode I already tried to repair broken packages. I got an error something like this: Message: 'not running quirks in partialUpgrad mode' Arguments: ()

So far I can:

- Enter boot-menu and pass it
- Enter grub-menu
- Enter TTY (sometimes)

I cannot:

- Use a bootable device, e.g a USB to reinstall xubuntu

My question:
- How can I check all my hardware in this case?
- What the hell is going on with my system?

More Info:
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
dpkg: error : reading package info file 'var/lib/dpkg/updates/0000': Input/output error

Thanks!

Comment: input/output error is not a good sign.. sounds like you may have a harddrive issue .. is there a reason you cant boot from a USB or CDRom? .. have you tried the Grub menu / advanced options and chose the recovery mode  and then the fsck option to check the hard drive and the dpkg option to try to fix any broken packages?

Comment: oops sorry didn't notice you did say you tried the dpkg option ... I still think the fsck option may show and hopefully correct issues you are having with the drive .. but im only guessing at this point :(

Comment: Thanks so far! "Check all file systems" does not produce any error. Seems fine, so far

Comment: hmmm .. you may have to look at your `/etc/fstab` and the output of `sudo blkid` and make sure that the partitions and UUIDS match in the fstab file. .. but .. its getting a bit over my skill level .. I think you will have to do it from recovery command prompt .. not sure if you have to mount it first to 'see' the fstab file .. haven't messed with the recovery much :( .. the slowness may just be a heavy load because of something not functioning properly in the OS ... but I guess you cant get into the actual full OS ... or I would suggest running `top` or `htop` if you have it installed

Comment: Alrighty! The bigger problem is that i cannot install a new op, as i get stuck when using the bootable usb (which I used to originally install the system).

Comment: so you used the USB to install it originally but it wont boot to it now? does it give any errors? .. can you be more specific as to what you mean by you get "stuck"

Comment: It select the device for booting. The next thing I see is a black screen with a cursor on the top left.  But I just doubled checked the USB- stick. There might be a problem with the USB stick (though i used it already for the last installation). So ill use a new one, and hope that I can finally simply install a whole new system.  I ll post an update in case it will work

Comment: good luck .. sorry I coudnt have been more help